# How to adjust the tabale width to match the page width

Tags: tables

The table generator creates the below latex format from the website, and I input this information into the latex; then the table is wider than the page width:
[image]

Therefore, I try to set out the column width as below, it’s seem work, but the second column doesn’t work
[image]

And I also tried to use \columnwidth to set out the table width to match with page width, but the result is still not working.
[image]

Here is my question on how to set out the latex format like the work presented below.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please do not post screenshots. Instead give us complete but minimal code showing the problem..

Answer (score -1):

Below is a hint, in the form of a Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Technology} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Adoption}\\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{UK} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Asia}\\
3D Printing & \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]